# Image icons do not look well formed in Custom Visual Studio tool window (VSIX)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I'm working on a VSIX (Visual Studio Extension) project. It contains a tool window to display information.

Tool windows was created based on a [walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138567.aspx) followed in MSDN.

I observed that Image icons (Png, jpg formats as per my tests) added to the Tool window are not look well formed (not in the original appearance),  time to time when I change the size or positions of the tool window (by drag and drop, dock and undock).

Image Icon used :  [Cross.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z70et.png)

Modified Source code for FirstToolWindowControl.xaml (as per above [walkthrough](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138567.aspx))

```
<UserControl x:Class="FirstToolWin.FirstToolWindowControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             Background="{DynamicResource VsBrush.Window}"
             Foreground="{DynamicResource VsBrush.WindowText}"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             Name="MyToolWindow">
    <Grid Width="auto" Height="auto">       
        <Image Margin="20" Source="C:\Cross.png" Width="16" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Malformed Image Screen capture: [MalformedImageIcon.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fV8X.png)

Appreciate anyone's assistance to find the root course and resolve the issue.
Thank you.

Comment: M, Where did you want to add this icon?

Comment: Within a stack panel which is a part of the above tool windows.         
 `<StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" Orientation="Horizontal">
 <Label Content="You can view this..."/>
 <Button Margin="1,0" Cursor="Hand" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem.Lot}" Background="Transparent">
  <Image Source="cross.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" /> 
 </Button>
</StackPanel>`

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, we also tried for both Vector (XAML based) and Raster images as well. Observed the same behavior.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, appreciate any feedback on this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XAML based Vector images instead of Raster image icons. We were able to find most of Standerd icons (XAML based) form [this](https://materialdesignicons.com/) repository.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, if possible, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue. Thanks for your sharing again:)

Answer (score 0):

One solution I could show it normally:

```
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <Image Width="16" Height="16" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor"
   RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased">
            <Image.Source>
                <BitmapImage DecodePixelWidth="200"  UriSource="C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\ColeVSIXProject\ColeVSIXProject\Resources\Test2.png" /> 
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </StackPanel>
```

Comment: I tried this option. It seems perfect some time and is not, as we change the position of the tool window (when resizing). This was the same observation I had before.

Comment: @Zameer M, I updated my answer, if possible, you could check it again. It would be related to the render scene.

Comment: Thanks for your response. With the new update, image distortions seems to be minimal. After further modifying the code's BitmapScalingMode to BitmapScalingMode="Fant" it improved a little bit but isn't perfect. Still it is an issue for images with rounded edges. Please let me know any other alternatives. Thanks

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT Is this a bug or a limitation in VSIX tool window?

Comment: @Zameer M, Does it have this issue in different machine? Actually I couldn't repro this issue in my side, it works well in my side. So I'm thinking about that whether it is related to the Windows Environment itself.

Comment: @Bandara, Do you mean that you get the same issue as Zameer?

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, Yes I have the same issue.

Comment: @JackZhai-MSFT, Yes, the issue exists in a huge number of Client machines at Production environment.